# Qt how to read an XML?

Tags: xml, qt, qt-creator

SOLUTION: I had to add Qt += xml to my .pro file

here's my problem:

myClass.h:

```
#include <QtXml/QDomDocument>
#include <QtXml/qdom.h>
[...]
```

myClass.cpp

```
[...]
QDomDocument doc("test");
[...]
```

on build I get the error:

```
collect2:ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong with this ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Qt-Creator 2.0.1, Windows 7 x64 Pro.

Comment: Don't you have another error lines when linking? Perhaps you miss a library for XML.

Comment: Give it a couple days and you can accept your answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add Qt += xml to my .pro file.

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer, which lets other people know you've fixed the problem. Then you can also remove the unnecessary "[SOLVED]" from the question title.

Comment: I still have to wait almost 2 days before being able to accept my own answer :|

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message I assume you aren't linking to QtXML.
I haven't used Qt-Creator, but I believe there is a simple way to activate/deactivate components of Qt for your program.